# Amazon Product API - Get Musician's Unique ID from Artist Name

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I'd like to query AWS for a Musician's ASIN from the artist's name. I'm not concerned about false matches at this point, I just want to discover the correct parameters that it'll take to get the job done.

Alternatively, I could query using an album's ASIN which I already have. Using the following parameters, I'm able to get the album's artist name, but not the artist ASIN.

Operation   => ItemSearch,
SearchIndex     => Music,
Artist      => Moby,
ResponseGroup   => Images,
AssociateTag    => Associate_tag

Thanks All!

**EDIT: I made a mistake labeling this as a "ASIN". What I'm looking for is the unique id for an artist. Looking at amazon.com/Shinedown/e/B00197I1JU illustrates the use of this unique id ("B00197I1JU"). I'm trying to get this value to store locally.**

Comment: Hi mavrck, did you find a solution for that? I've the same problem.

Comment: No, not directly. I ended up just not recording Amazon's id for an artist. I had an id from other services (Last.fm, MusicBrainz, etc.), so I left it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ItemAttributes` response group to get a list of products and their ASIN values that are related to your search criteria. This response group will also contain such information as artist name, binding, list price, etc.

You can use more than one `ResponseGroup` attributes to get both the `ItemAttributes` and `Images` response group with the same call.

Comment: "ItemAttributes" does not include the ASIN of the Artist, only the artist name and the ASIN of the album. This is where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: An ASIN is assigned to each product that Amazon sells. ASINs are not assigned to artists only their albums that Amazon lists. I don't understand what you are looking for. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: While I'm making the assumption that they would refer to this as ASIN as well, it may be called something else. Looking at http://www.amazon.com/Shinedown/e/B00197I1JU illustrates the use of this unique id ("B00197I1JU"). I'm trying to get this value to store locally.

Comment: It looks like Amazon is using an ASIN to refer to some type of grouping. However, using this ASIN as a parameter to an `ItemLookup` request returns an error with "This item is not accessible through ECS". I can only speculate as to what this means but it does hint to me that you won't be able to do a reverse operation and lookup a grouping's ASIN. So, unfortunately the answer to your question is that this is not possible. However, I am no expert and perhaps someone else can offer a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is where I've arrived as well. I'm hoping that my lack of Amazon experience is causing me to miss something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

ASIN—Amazon Standard Item Number
An alphanumeric token that uniquely identifies items in the Amazon marketplace.
All items in the marketplace have an ASIN. This is by far the most common identifier. ASINs are used
by the majority of Product Advertising API operations.

So ASIN is related only with the item not with the item description or details...

Comment: This is correct, the ASIN is per-product not per-artist or anything like that. I have multiple songs on amazon, all the same artist [me] and all have a unique ASIN. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to note that AWS is deprecated when it comes to the store, you should be using MWS and here is the docs for the correct part of MWS you need V138592989.pdf">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiReference.*V138592989*.pdf and here is the link [hard to find] to the main MWS area. https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/182-3268148-9799929?ie=UTF8&section=products&group=products&version=latest

Keep in mind that without an active pro seller account you will not be able to get a developer key if you are trying to build apps that integrate with private parts of the amazon API. I just went through this and had to grab the free trial long enough to get a key, which still works after you cancel the trial.

Also, you can not receive any support from MWS without that pro seller account! I spent over an hour on the phone with my AWS rep and he didn't even know how to access the MWS site. He had to call them only to be told [by them] that they didn't know how to access their API either, this was all too new for them.

I did eventually get everything working for me after scouring through their docs and downloading the correct API for MWS.

Good Luck!